# Error while trying to save and load a Logistic Regression Model in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, model, pyspark

I have split my input data into train_df,test_df and val_df. I have trained my model with the train_df data and wish to save it and load it.

My CODE :

```
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=100)
lrModel = lr.fit(train_df)

predictions = lrModel.transform(val_df)

evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction")
print("Prediction : \n")
print(evaluator.evaluate(predictions))

accuracy = predictions.filter(predictions.label == predictions.prediction).count() / float(val_set.count())
print("Accuracy : \n")
print(accuracy)

lrModel.write().save("/home/vijay18/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lrModel")
model = LogisticRegressionModel()
model.load("/home/vijay18/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lrModel")
```

This is the error i get on the terminal. The first three lines of the error are for the saving the model..  the rest are for loading it.

Error :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
18/07/17 20:04:01 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
```

Answer (score 1):

`load` is not intended to be called on an instance. It should be

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegressionModel

LogisticRegressionModel.load(path)
```

Comment: Now error:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
18/07/16 20:41:56 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_detach'" in <bound method LogisticRegressionModel.__del__ of LogisticRegressionModel_43d793f059c6e3acb2a2> ignored